# Ways to predict the preservation of functional domains in fusion proteins

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, protein-folding, structure-prediction

My lab is synthetically creating fusion proteins consisting of an enzyme attached to a [zinc finger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_finger) through a [linker](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3726540/). We can attach the zinc finger to the enzyme at either its N-terminus or its C-terminus, but are unsure how to decide which terminus order to use. Have there been any attempts to predict the preservation of proteins' functional domains when they are combined into fusion proteins or, more specifically, to assess the relative qualities of different fusion protein orderings?

Comment: Naively I would think that if either domain binds with/interacts with large molecules in the cytosol, it might be better to place that downstream to minimize any effect on translation. Why not just try it both ways and see what happens in terms of synthesis yield and functionality?

Comment: A quick non-specialized search for "fusion protein zinc finger" brings up several papers dating back over 20 years. Have you looked at these papers to see where the fusions were made and whether the DNA binding activity was maintained? It would seem more appropriate to consider experience rather than prediction. And please note that you are expected to do your "homework" before posting here and to indicate in a post that you have done so and what you have found. (And, personally, I find it strange that any lab funded to undertake such studies is not aware of previous work.)